# Reject strings that only contain spaces

Tags: python, while-loop, count

I have the following code to input a string, and reject it in some cases:

```py
x = input() 
while x.count('')>=1:  
    print('type non empty text only')
    x = input()
```

However, I want to reject strings that contain only spaces, and accept all strings that contain at least one non-space character. The code above mistakenly rejects many strings that should be accepted.

Examples of strings that should be accepted or rejected:

```
'   '   ->  reject
''      ->  reject
'   a ' ->  accept
```

Comment: Could you give some more examples of strings you want to accept?

Comment: You are checking for the empty string, not a white space. By convention a string always contains len(string) + 1 empty spaces. If you want to check if the string is not empty do while x:

Comment: Would `'  ' in x` fit what you want? It checks whether there are two consecutive spaces in `x`.

Comment: it should not accept long consecutive spaces but it should allow normal letters for example.

Comment: What about mulit token strings like `"abc def"`, `" abc  def"`

Comment: Add a few examples of which string to reject

Comment: @DaniMesejo If it has even one single character other than empty spaces it should be acceptable.

Comment: is this `" "` acceptable? this contains a whitespace character

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can use `str.strip()` and check with `''` like below:

```
x = input() 
while x.strip() == '':
    print('type non empty text only')
    x = input()
```

Answer (score 1):

This?

```
x = input() 
while len(x)==0 or set(x) == {' '}:
    print('type non empty text only')
    x = input()
```

or

```
while all(c==' ' for c in x):
```

Comment: or alternatively `set(x) <= set(string.whitespace)`

Comment: or `all(c in string.whitespace for c in x)`

Answer (score 1):

To avoid the entire class of strings only made up of white space, you can use [`str.strip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip):

```
while not (x := input()).strip():  
    print('type non empty text only')
```

Comment: nice, but note the `:=` operator only works in Python 3.8+

Comment: @rv.kvetch If you want to avoid repeating the statement `x = input()` before and inside the loop, but don't want to depend on support for `:=`, the alternative is `while True:` with a conditional `break`. This is my preference for the time being.